# How to redirect New User to different page one time only?

Tags: meteor

ok so when my app starts after the first time you sign up I want to redirect the user to a different page.

In my server code I have this

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
Hooks.onCreateUser = function () {
Meteor.Router.to('/newUser');
   }
});
```

but I want users to be redirected to another page if they have already been on more then once so I have this in my client code, it always defaults to the client, what am I doing wrong?

```
Hooks.onLoggedIn = function () {
Meteor.Router.to('/new');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect a signed user, simply set up a flag within user object denoting whether he was redirected:

```
Hooks.onLoggedIn = function (){
  if(!Meteor.user()) return;
  if(!Meteor.user().returning) {
    Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$set: {returning: true}});
    Meteor.Router.to('/new');
  }
}
```

Make sure to publish & subscribe to the `returning` field of user collection!

---

If you want similar functionality for all visitors, use cookies.

```
Hooks.onLoggedIn = function (){
  if(!Cookie.get('returning')) {
    Cookie.set('returning', true);
    Meteor.Router.to('/new');
  }
}
```

Here's the handy package for that: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/cookies

Comment: hmm thanks but im looking for something different I think or need a little more help, when the first time the user signs in, I want a message to appear on the screen at /new but on subsequent logins, I don't want that message appearing so my dilemma is trying to figure out how to make that a one time thing

Answer (score 0):

Create collection 'ExistingUsers' to keep track.

```
 if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Deps.autorun(function () {
  if(Meteor.userId())
//will run when a user logs in - now check if userId is in 'ExistingUsers'
//If not display message and put userId in 'ExistingUsers'
});
```

Alternatively add field 'SeenMessage' to User collection